# Intercept HTTP Traffic from browser and show the headers in c#

Tags: c#

I need to create a c# application that intercepts http traffic from the user's browser (Firefox, chrome) by adding proxy settings in the browser and then show the HTTP headers of the request without using any third party plugins like FiddlerCore.

I found some examples using HttpListener but none of them show the headers.

Comment: I guess I'm missing something in your post - looks like you are trying to *create* an application but no one provided you with *complete source* and it is a problem... Consider re-wording your post and showing code you already have so there is no chance on can have such a wrong impression.

Answer (score 0):

if you interested to build a simple proxy server then you can take look here.

http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/288683-a-simple-proxy-server-in-c%23/
there are few lines from there

I have written a simple and minimalist HTTP proxy server that runs on command line.
 In the Start() method, a TcpListener blocks until it gets a client request and creates a new thread (ThreadHandleClient method) that processes this client, fetches its url and relays data.